# Porting Applications License

Tags: licensing, porting

I'm thinking of porting some of GNOME to Minix to help me study C. If the program I want to port is a copyleft license (e.g. GPL), does the ported version have to be licensed under the same license, or can I change the license?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a modified GPL program must be released under the GPL.

Comment: Alright Thanks. I though it would have to as it is technically "derived" but I just wanted to make sure.